# How to read fsck output?

Tags: linux, fsck

I want to understand the fsck output, I did not find it explained anywhere. The following it's output of the fsck command on a luks encrypted ext4 drive (unmounted). What's the `(1993/0/0 errors)` supposed to mean? What's the fraction supposed to describe `Files: clean, 633043/61046784 files, 143545156/244181760 blocks`? If there's any primary source with GRAPHICAL description of what each section of the output means please cite it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It would have been kind and polite to cite the output as ASCII characters instead of pasting an image, so outsourcing the typing to the answering guys.

Comment: (1) [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). (2) `fsck` is a front-end for *various* `fsck.fstype` programs. The output you're asking about is from `fsck.ext2`, `fsck.ext3` or `fsck.ext4`, they are all symlinks to `e2fsck`. Other `fsck.something` programs may and do give *different* output. E.g. in my Debian `fsck.btrfs` is just a shell script that tells me I can run `btrfs check` manually, it does nothing more. So the title should rather be "How to read output of `e2fsck`".

Comment: @dodrg quite the oversight on my part. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

- `/dev/mapper/samsung_crypt` tells you that you are not at the physical partition but one onion layer further.
- `[sudo] password for jd:` tells us this onion layer is going to be decrypted with the credentials of "jd".
- `fsck ... \n efs2chk ... \n ... blocks` tells us your encrypted partition has an EXT filesystem, no issues found and enough resources left.
  (*"number"`/`"number"* says *"used"`/`"maximum-possible"*)
- `sudo fsck -f -c -y /dev/mapper/samsung_crypt` starts a forced search for bad blocks.
  => If its wise to do a search for *physical* errors on a *virtual* filesystem, I'm not convinced.
  => To find physical bad blocks, you should check the physical device!
- The "bad block test" shows errors.

  - `6.69% done` says the test hasn't finished yet.
  - The values (1993/0/0)  decode as the number of  `(read/write/corruption)`-errors.
    So you have 1993 read errors while only 6.69% of the filesystem has been scanned currently.
    But you should remember: *You scan a virtual filesystem for physical errors .....*

You should not do `-c` on the decrypted layer of a crypt container.
Do the check on the pysical layer like `/dev/sda3` to get results of value.

To get some more info about checking for bad blocks you should read `man 8 badblocks` (the tool behind this part of the fsck test).
Also the descriptions of [ArchLinux: badblocks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/badblocks) are quite helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Where is the `(read/write/corruption)` documented for fsck?

Comment: I updated the answer to provide some material to read. The hint about the `(read/write/corruption)` can be found at the [paragraph 5.2 in the ArchLinx-Wiki "badblocks"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/badblocks#Before_filesystem_creation).

Comment: `If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or directory.` -- from mkfs.ext4's man page. While `-c` make use of `badblocks`, it does things on filesystem level as well, so `You should not do -c on the decrypted layer of a crypt container.
Do the check on the pysical layer like /dev/sda3 to get results of value.` is not quite right. (Besides, the mapping of logical blocks between the container and the underlying device should be fixed anyway.)

Comment: On the other hand, I wonder whether how much sense `-c` make these days, especially in the case of SSD where LBAs are often constantly mapped to different memory whenever there's a new write.

Comment: @TomYan : Well, a "block" is a physical position on the media. An "inode" is a logical item of a filesystem. If you suspect physical defects, marking only logical objects as "do not use" is somewhat not persistent. Encapsulating this in a virtual Object like a crypto container is the next step to get more distance from the physical reality.

Comment: Nope, block IS a logical address in many context (like I said, even LBA on SSD is not at all a physical position). What `-c` really does here is test the logical blocks and record those defected one in the filesystem metadata so that they will not be used. While the container is an extra logical layer, each logical block of the container corresponds to a logical block of the underlying drive in a static manner (and inode is not relevant in that context).

Comment: It's too late, I think I fubared the crypt by performing that operation on the logical drive instead of the physical one and now it can't be mounted. Sigh.

Comment: @AspiringDev I highly doubt that it is the reason, since regardless how badblocks is called, it does not perform any "low-level" / "physical" interaction as some might think. (Not to mention that the block test part should be read-only.) (In fact I don't think fsck.ext4 would even start anyway if you run it on the underlying device, since it should just quit because there's no filesystem detected; that shouldn't change regardless of whether you passed `-c`)

Comment: @TomYan when I try to mount the crypt now I'm getting `mount: /mnt/Files: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/samsung_crypt. dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.`